# Bind a Java process to a virtual interface

Tags: linux, networking, java, bind, bindings

I'm trying to bind a java process to a specific virtual interface having IP address `<myIFaddr>` as follows:

```
export BIND_ADDR=<myIFaddr> LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so
exec java -jar ppp.jar
```

The program `ppp.jar` simply makes a request on an HTTP server, which replies sending back the IP address of the client, printing this address to stdout.
As a result, the java program prints the IP address of the "physical interface" (non the virtual one, having a different IP address).

Is there a way to solve this problem, applying a correct/different binding?

Thanks

Comment: The reason it is doing this depends on a lot of things.  For instance, does the virtual interface have its own path to the server, or is it going through another interface and being NATted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java socket in your application you can use the bind function as follows:

```
mysocket=new Socket();
mysocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(<myIFaddr>, port));
```

naturally you have to modify the code to take in input  in your Java application.